Does a vector space $V$ of dimension $p>0$ always have a spanning set of $p+2$ vectors?
I know since $V$ is of dimension $p$, it must have a spanning set of $p$ vectors (a basis).
However, can we always find $2$ extra vectors to add to it? In other words, is it possible for a vector space to have only at most $p+1$ vectors in it?
Update: Let's say I only consider vector space over the field of $\mathbb R$?

You could look at some examples, for instance a vector space of small enough dimension $p$, over a field of also small-valued characteristic...

I think that you should be able to prove for yourself that this only fails when $p=1$ and the field in question is $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Having a spanning set of $p+2$ vectors is very different from the full vector space having $p+1$ vectors. But as others pointed out in the comments, if you look at a vector space over a very small field (think when?), then you might not even have $p+2$ vectors. But otherwise if you have at least $p+2$ vectors, you can add them into a basis to get a spanning set. The 'spanning work' will the done by the basis elements, so it doesn't matter what you add into that set.
Hope this helps. :)
